# Openerp7 migration to odoo 11

Tags: migration, odoo, openerp-7, odoo-11

I am trying to migrate a database from Openerp7 to Odoo11.
I have done this before but now this database has custom fields and models which were created through UI not custom modules, and now makes a problem.

```
cona@cona-cons:~$ tailf /var/tmp/openupgrade/migration.log
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
File "/var/tmp/openupgrade/8.0/server/openerp/models.py", line 3052, in _setup_fields
field.setup(self.env)
File "/var/tmp/openupgrade/8.0/server/openerp/fields.py", line 470, in   setup
self._setup_regular(env)
File "/var/tmp/openupgrade/8.0/server/openerp/fields.py", line 1792, in _setup_regular
invf = comodel._fields[self.inverse_name]
KeyError: u'x_payment_line_id'
```

Is there any way to remove the custom models and fields (as they are not needed and get a clean db for migration?

Thanks

Comment: In the 8/9/10/11 (new db) you can manually create x_ fields. The easiest way would be to delete custom fields / move them to custom modules (you would have to charge the customer for this) and migrate as usually.

Comment: yes i am aware of that but im asking how to delete all of them in a clean way, because when i erase the columns from the tables, or the x_ table itself, the migration fails because somehow it is searching for these fields.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Whoever created the fields should provide the documentation. When you delete them from Odoo and then update Odoo it will replace customised views with original Odoo. This way you will have Odoo like a brand new and no custom fields present.
BTW: are you using OCA scripts?

Comment: yes im using OCA scripts. the openupgrade project. For my work it doesnt matter if the custom fields and models exist in the new version,, thats  why i was asking if someone knows how to erase those so i can upgrade the db without errors